# Does Windows Phone 7 supported Google Map in his Web-Browser?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Anyone can tell me about that link "http://maps.google.com" windows phone web-browser supported or not?
    I m trying but unable to get that..

please anyone can help, i need that solution

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

No. Google renders a *places*-centric application for IE9, most likely due to the browser not supporting touch events.